# How to handle covariance within a kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, dsl, covariance

I'm rather new to Kotlin. I order to get a grip on building dsl's I'm running into the following challenge.

I'm building a logger implementation using coroutines as an exercise. The latter is not really relevant for the moment.

What I would like to accomplish, is the following

```
logger {
  level = LogLevel.INFO
  appender<PrintStream> {
  }
  formatter {
  }
}
```

appender is actually a generic implementation of an Appender interface. Now I would like to build a concrete implementation, let's say ConsoleAppender.

So I have an Appender interface

```
/**
 * An appender knows how to write out the data.
 */
interface Appender<in T>  {
    // cool, let's use coroutines...
    open suspend fun writeToLog(message: String) {}
}
```

and I have a ConsoleAppender implementation

```
/**
 * Implementation of ConsoleAppender
 * that writes out content to the console
 */
class ConsoleAppender(val printer: PrintStream = System.out) : Appender<PrintStream>() {
    override suspend fun writeToLog(message: String) {
        printer.print(message)
    }
}
```

and a Logger class that has a reference to this appender

```
class Logger<T> {
    var logLevel: LogLevel = LogLevel.INFO
    var appender: Appender<T>? = null
...
}
```

At the moment I have no idea how to construct an implementation of Appender.

Now I would like to build a dsl based on the classes that are used by the logger.

```
fun <T> logger(buildLogger: Logger<T>.() -> Unit): Logger<T> {
    val logger = Logger<T>()
    logger.buildLogger()
    return logger
}

fun <T> appender(buildAppender: Appender<T>.() -> Unit): Appender<T> {
    val appender = How can I create a specific instance of appender?
    appender.buildAppender()
    return appender
}
```

Has anyone a suggestion how I could accomplish this?

Comment: That's quite a broad question. Can you describe where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: That's true. I've tried to be more specific. But any tips are welcome. I'm in a learning phase, so I would like to know how I could handle covariance in a DSL.

Comment: Your edit made it much clearer! I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Your main problem here isn't really related to DSLs or variance, but to how to find a specific implementation of appender. Consider using service locator pattern. But honestly, it feels to me that you should design it like this: `logger { consoleAppender { ... } }`. User of DSL should decide on the implementation of the appender - it should not be provided automatically. What should happen if there are multiple implementations of `PrintStream` appender?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you.  The user of this API could easily use the console appender directly.